# recursion not working for me

Tags: python, numpy, recursion

So I am working with `numpy` and I've been asked to create a function that returns the input "grades of students" as the average of the grades in a map without the use of a loop, and the only thing that came to my mind to make this possible is recursion

```
def hw_grade_average(_array):
   condition=len(_array)
   stop=condition
   start=0
   outp=[]
   def calc(inp):
      if stop-1==inp:
           return outp
       if stop!=inp:
           calc=float(sum(_array[start]))/float(len(_array[start]))
           outp.append(calc)
       return calc(inp+1)
    _returned = np.asarray(outp,dtype=float)
    return calc(start)
```

in input for an example

```
hw_grade_average(hw_grades)
```

where

```
    hw_grades=
           array([[ 57,  99, 100,  81,  77],
                  [ 70,  91,  57,  77,  56],
                  [ 74,  89,  62, 100,  99],
                  [ 61,  53,  42,  65,  21],
                  [ 81,  65,  40,  37,  60],
                  [ 75,  88, 100,  92,  95]])
```

The output I am looking for is

> array([82.8, 70.2, 84.8, 48.4, 56.5, 90. ])

but I get that an

> TypeError: 'float' object is not callable

Comment: Simply `hw_grades.mean(axis=1)`?

Comment: `return calc(start+1)` that doesn't do it? @MooingRawr

Comment: If you are working with numpy, then just use numpy.

Comment: Especially when using `numpy` recursion is not a substitute for loops.

Comment: BTW, you got that TypeError because you clobbered the `calc` function with the `calc = float(sum...` assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `result = np.average(hwgrades, axis=1)`? You will find the [documentation here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.average.html).